# Fetch data in mysql Databse automatically to a website

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, web

I have configured a table which insert temperature values to a database. Now I need to retrieve database value to a website. I am new to web developing. Are there any templates that I can use for this?
MySQL table structure is

```
CREATE table digitemp 
dtKey int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
time timestamp NOT NULL,
SerialNumber varchar(17) NOT NULL,
Fahrenheit decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (dtKey),
KEY serial_key (SerialNumber),
KEY time_key (time)
```

Comment: if you're completely new to this stuff, follow some tutorials to learn the basics rather than asking for specific examples; http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Comment: @MLeFevre For the love of everything that is good in this world, don't point the guy to the mysql functions on W3Schools. The mysql functions are no longer recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Small basic example using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php):

```
//Connect to MySQL
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=YOURDBNAME', 'YourUsername', 'YourPassword');

//prepare your SELECT query
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT dtKey, time, SerialNumber, Fahrenheit FROM digitemp");

//Execute your query
$sth->execute();

//Loop through each row
while($row = $sth->fetchAll()){
    print_r($row);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) to interact with your database from a web application.

Comment: Hello Wayne. Wouldn't it be better to use the `query()` instead of `prepare()` ? Because we are not including any placeholders or binding any values in it. So, is there a need of preparing it ?

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran Yes, but it's a good idea for beginners to get their head around the concept of prepared statements so that they don't choose to conveniently ignore them and treat PDO like the mysql functions. Also, I'm guessing that this guy will be selecting on conditions in the near future. Doesn't make sense for him to be just dumping the entire table out onto the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the code for this. Use PDO or mysqli for the db interaction and fetch the records from the db and display it in your page. There are so many tutorials available, if you  do a quick Google search :)

Useful for learning PDO: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Bookmark it if necessary. :)

Comment: i need to submit this as soon as possible. are there any templates regarding this?

Comment: no.this is a part of my project.i just need to have a table which automatically retrieve. planning to put this int LAMP and access from outside

Comment: ok.. Have you tried testing the code that Wayne Whitty had posted as a solution (above/below this post) ? It has everything you needed. Just fiddle up certain parts like, the dbname, dbusername and dbpassword with your values. And it would work. From that, you could change it accordingly to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of answer you are looking for.
Do you want to do this in HTML, or can you do it server side in PHP, or client side in Javascript?

For PHP, you can just connect to a database. You can find more on how to this here:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

In your case, your code would look like this (not tested....)

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("myServer","myName","myPassword");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("myDatabase", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SerialNumber, Fahrenheit FROM digitemp");

echo "<table><tr><th>SerialNumber</th><th>Fahrenheit</th></tr>"
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<tr><td>".$row['SerialNumber'] . "</td><td> " . $row['Fahrenheit']."</td></tr>";
  echo "</table>";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go, note: check out these websites 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

```
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password"); //enter your username,password
  if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("databaseName", $con); //enter your database name

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM digitemp");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['SerialNumber '] . " " . $row['Fahrenheit '];
  echo "<br />";
  }

mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score -1):

Go through basics of [MySQL connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)  and [MySQl Query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

Answer (score -1):

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password"); //enter your username,password
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("databaseName", $con); //enter your database name

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM digitemp");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['SerialNumber '] . " " . $row['Fahrenheit '];
echo "<br />";
}
```

mysql_close($con);
if you got any deprecated error  then try like  that

```
 while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

Comment: @ Wayne Whitty
try PDO

    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

Comment: you can review this link [link] http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/